# Is it possible to refresh a single RLMObject?

Tags: ios, realm

I have a RLMObject that I wish to refresh from the underlying tightdb. I don't necessarily need to refresh all objects on that realm (i.e. `[[myObject realm] refresh]`) because it feels like overkill: I'm doing this fairly regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Joe from Realm here — you shouldn’t need to worry about refreshing manually unless you’re on a thread that doesn’t have a run loop, or if you are sending your own notifications which you need to see before ours. (On a thread with a run loop, your Realms are refreshed at every tick.)

Even if you are on a thread without a run loop, we don’t give you an option to refresh a single object because that would mess with your consistency, relationships, etc. The performance impact of refreshing an entire Realm should be negligible anyway, unless you are holding references to thousands of objects.

I’d be interested to hear why you feel compelled to refresh your Realm in the first place (maybe we should address this in our docs?), and if you are seeing any performance issues with the refresh. Can you give any more details?

Comment: Hi Joe, I have a RLMObject which has a local status representing it's sync state with my server. I update that status property on an background GCD thread. I have a reference to the same object in my VC and update the UI from the main thread on a timer (I have a countdown timer running). I'm in the main thread and AFACS the RLMObject isn't uploading. Could it be a threading/ownership problem?

Comment: I'm currently refreshing the realm which isn't causing me performance problems: it just felt wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the details, refreshing the realm in this case is the right thing to do here

Comment: Thanks. Timer == my own notification I guess :-) Is there any reason why there isn't a single object refresh or that I can't set my really to auto refresh like RLMResults does? For the record, the latter is cool but not always what I want - I'd like to be able to freeze an RLMResults without copying it into an NSArray..

Comment: I believe we don't have an autorefresh on single objects to avoid any of the inconsistencies listed above, protecting the user in a sense. We hear you on the ability to freeze an RLMResults :). It's a critical part for us to add fine grained notifications, there are some discussions on github around it. Definitely one of the top priorities right now.